# How to highlight rows if there are two elements in a column for a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in a format:

```
d = {'vertex': [0,0,0,1,1] ,'hour': [1, 1,2,1,2], 'value': ['sun', 'watermelon','sun','watermelon','sun']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How can I highlight rows where there is both `'sun'` and `'watermelon'` in `'value'` column for a grouped dataframe by two columns `[vertex,hour]`. Which means that first two rows should be highlighted, because for vertex 0 and hour 1 there are bot values 'sun' and 'watermelon' in the grouped dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
def highlight_by_list(x):
    #list of values 
    L = ['sun', 'watermelon']
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    # condition
    m = df.groupby(['vertex','hour'])['value'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(L))
    # empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

    # set all matched rows to yellow 
    df1.loc[m, :] = c1
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight_by_list, axis=None).to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'vertex': [0,0,1,1,1] ,
       'hour': [1, 1,2,2,2],
     'value': ['sun', 'watermelon','apple','watermelon','sun']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def highlight_by_list(x):
    #list of values 
    L = ['sun', 'watermelon']
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    # conditions for test by substring and also for get only rows from L
    m1 = df.groupby(['vertex','hour'])['value'].transform(lambda x: set(L).issubset(set(x)))
    m2 = df['value'].isin(L)
    # empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

    # set all matched rows to yellow 
    df1.loc[m1 & m2, :] = c1
    return df1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is almost what I wanted. I substituted your line set(x) == set(L) with set(L).issubset(set(x)), because there is a possibility that there appears a string which is irrelevant like for example 'apple'. I have an additional question: What if there is an additional row with hour and vertex where the condition is met, but the string is irrelevant for the condition for example 'apple'. Right now it would also highlight this row. How can I only highlight the rows in question meaning the ones that contain 'sun' and 'watermelon' ?

Comment: @RyszardEggink - Give me some minutes, please.

Comment: @RyszardEggink - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rows_series = df[['vertex','hour']].duplicated(keep=False)
rows = rows_series[rows_series].index.values
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: yellow' if x.name in rows else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```